# How to remove the new line character from a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I am trying to remove the new line character from a nested list of this type -

```
[['Full Name', ' Email Address'],
['Blossom Gill', ' blossom@xyz.edu'],
['Hayes Delgado', ' nonummy@utnisia.com'],
['Petra Jones', ' ac@xyz.edu'],
['Oleg Noel', ' noel@liberomauris.ca'],
['Ahmed Miller', ' ahmed.miller@nequenonquam.co.uk'],
['Macaulay Douglas', ' mdouglas@xyz.edu']]
```

Because when creating a csv in python from `csv.writer(output.csv).writerows(given_list)` , 
its making output like this:-

```
Full Name, Email Address

Blossom Gill, blossom@xyz.edu

Hayes Delgado, nonummy@utnisia.com

Petra Jones, ac@xyz.edu

Oleg Noel, noel@liberomauris.ca

Ahmed Miller, ahmed.miller@nequenonquam.co.uk
```

**With SPACES which I don't want**

Comment: You have spaces in your second item in the array, what do you expect?

Comment: I don't know why it was not before, but now I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string `strip` function to remove spaces.

Inside a list comprehension, it gives:

```py
data = [['Full Name', ' Email Address'],
        ['Blossom Gill', ' blossom@xyz.edu'],
        ['Hayes Delgado', ' nonummy@utnisia.com'],
        ['Petra Jones', ' ac@xyz.edu'],
        ['Oleg Noel', ' noel@liberomauris.ca'],
        ['Ahmed Miller', ' ahmed.miller@nequenonquam.co.uk'],
        ['Macaulay Douglas', ' mdouglas@xyz.edu']]

new_data = [[name.strip(), email.strip()] for name, email in data]
print(new_data)
```

Comment: Thank You, for answer. But problem is that when I am using this `writer.writerows(list_name)` function in my local python (Anaconda python 3.7.4), there it's giving one blank line after each row printed in the output file.

Answer (score 1):

You can rework your list by removing spaces with str.split():

```
a = [['Full Name', ' Email Address'],
['Blossom Gill', ' blossom@xyz.edu'],
['Hayes Delgado', ' nonummy@utnisia.com'],
['Petra Jones', ' ac@xyz.edu'],
['Oleg Noel', ' noel@liberomauris.ca'],
['Ahmed Miller', ' ahmed.miller@nequenonquam.co.uk'],
['Macaulay Douglas', ' mdouglas@xyz.edu']]

# Magic trick here:
a = [[x.strip(), y.strip()] for x, y in a]


print(a) # [['Full Name', 'Email Address'], ['Blossom Gill', 'blossom@xyz.edu'], ['Hayes Delgado', 'nonummy@utnisia.com'], ['Petra Jones', 'ac@xyz.edu'], ['Oleg Noel', 'noel@liberomauris.ca'], ['Ahmed Miller', 'ahmed.miller@nequenonquam.co.uk'], ['Macaulay Douglas', 'mdouglas@xyz.edu']]
```